What is a good algorithm for placement of text labels near objects?
I have a rectangular map filled with objects of different sizes which each have a corresponding text label that must be placed as close to them as possible while not overlapping with any text labels or objects. The text can also be rotated 90 degrees if needed.
The specific case involves placement of text on a pcb board, where the objects are components and the text labels are there names.
I have started looking into methods such as simulated annealing.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It appears the problem could be modelled as an integer-linear programming (ILP) problem with binary-valued variables (i.e, each variable must equal 0 or 1).

Let i index components
Let j index locations where labels may be applied
Let Ji be the set of feasible locations for component i
Let Ij be the set of components that could occupy location j

Note that the sets Ij are computed from the sets Ji.
We define the following binary variables.
xij equals 1 if the label for component i is to occupy location j, else equals 0, for each i and all j in Ji
ILP problems customarily have a linear function of the variables that is to be maximized or minimized. Here, however, any feasible solution (i.e., any solution that satisfies the constraints) suffices, hence the objective function being max 0. The formulation is as follows.
max 0
subject to:
ΣjϵJixij = 1 for all i
ΣiϵIjxij ≤ 1 for all j
The first group of constraints ensures that for each component i its label is placed in exactly one of the locations in the set of possible locations that have been identified, Ji. The second group of constraints ensures that at most one label is placed at each location.
The ILP package would terminate with an optimal solution (which in fact would be any feasible solution) or with the determination that no feasible solution exists.
It's not clear whether the problem could be solved in an acceptable time with an ILP software package. That would depend on the numbers of components and acceptable locations for labels and the efficiency of the ILP package.

This problem is a restricted form of the Exact Hitting Set problem, which is NP-complete. The additional restrictions here are that the valid label positions are rectangles, and can therefore only intersect in restricted ways -- and while it's possible that these restrictions mean your problem might escape NP-completeness, I'm 99% sure it won't. If it is NP-complete as I suspect, this means that no efficient algorithm is known that will solve every case.
An example restriction in your problem comes from considering the case of 5 label positions arranged as a small "ladder": three "rungs" A, B and C, and two "sides" L and R. It's clear that any rectangle that intersects the top and and bottom rung, and both sides, must also intersect the middle rung. More formally, this tells us that if there are pairwise nonintersecting label positions A, B and C, each of them intersects with label positions L and R, and L and R themselves do not intersect, then for some pair of label positions drawn from {A, B, C} it must be the case that any other label position that intersects L, R and both positions in that pair, it intersects all three of {A, B, C}.
  LLLLL    RRR
  LLLAAAAAAAAAAA
  LLLAAAAAAAAAAA
  LLLLL    RRR
  LLLLBBBBBBRR
  LLLLL    RRR
  LCCCCCCCCCCCC
  LCCCCCCCCCCCC
  LCCCCCCCCCCCC
  LLLLL    RRR

In terms of practical algorithms, if you can restrict the set of valid label positions to at most 2 per label, you can frame the problem as 2-SAT, which can be solved very efficiently.
